# Why can't I define a "variable variable" as static in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Why does the following (example) code block:

```
function test($ip)
{
   $handler = 'curl_' . str_replace('.', '_', $ip);
   static $$handler = NULL;
}

test('1.1.1.1');
```

return the following error message?

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in <file> on line <line>
```

If possible, please try not to suggest better ways to use the curl library (like curl_multi). I have an application which is working and performing very well. When it comes to libcurl, I have a curl() function that at some point will do something like this:

```
  // we want the handler to survive multiple invocations of this function (this allows for HTTP Keep-Alive)
  static $conn = NULL;

  if (!isset($conn)) {
     // the handler was not previously initialized; do it now before sending the first request
     $conn = curl_init();
  }
  else {
     // the handler was previously initialized; reset the connection properties before sending further requests
     curl_reset($conn);
  }
```

This works great, however, a few scripts can call `curl()` with different destination servers (interleaving requests between them). In that case, the function wastes time closing/opening new connections.

I would like my `curl()` function to use a unique handler per server (hence my failing code block above). I thought to generate a unique handler name using a variable variable (which is not a problem - for instance, curl_192_168_1_1). Then, I thought to make that variable variable static, at which point, `curl()` would continue as normal in the working block.

Note that changing the syntax to:

```
static ${$handler} = NULL;
```

doesn't make any difference.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because the variable name needs to be known at compile time, that's how `static` works. Why don't you simply use a `static` array into which you insert the different connections? That's pretty much always the answer whenever you think you need "variable variables".

Comment: Sound like you should have a look at OOP to abstract different connections without doing this hocus pocus....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **Note** in the documentation page of [`static` variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) that says:

> Static declarations are resolved in compile-time.

On the other hand, [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#language.variables.variable) means the name of such a variable is stored in another variable and it might not be available at the compile time.

In your example, the name of the variable you want to declare as `static` is computed on the runtime using the value of the `$ip` function argument.

---

The problem you are trying to solve has a different solution. For example, you can store the open handlers in a static array:

```
function test($ip)
{
    static $handlers = array();

    // Generate an ID that identifies the server
    $id = 'curl_' . str_replace('.', '_', $ip);

    // If no cUrl handler has been created for this server then ...
    if (! array_key_exists($handler, $id)) {
        // ... open a new handler
        $curl = curl_open($ip);
        // ... configure it...
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(/* ... */));
        // ... and store it to be reused when needed
        $handlers[$id] = $curl;
    }

    // Return the already open cUrl handler
    return $handlers[$id];
}
```

A better solution is to encapsulate the data (`$handlers`) and the code (`function test()`) into a class.